# Is there a single jquery ui package that include all the themes available on the official website?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to try different themes, so I need all the themes. But the official web site only provide package which include the base and another theme.

Is there a single jquery ui package that include all the themes available on the official website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-download-builderthemeroller-status/ appears to have zip files that contain all the themes but **I'm not really sure if it is for the latest version of JQuery UI**.